# Ubuntu 22.04 freezes frequently

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, freeze, cuda

My ubuntu 22.04 desktop was working fine until recently after I installed a bunch of drivers like `cuda, cudnn, tensorrt`. Now, it freezes frequently; network manager does not work, terminal does not work, system monitor does not open, even `restart` does not work. I have to do the hard shut down. Then maybe it works for a while. I suspect it has something to do with the graphics driver. But I could not figure anything out as it is installed properly. `nvidia-smi` works fine, `nvcc --version` shows `cuda11.6` too. It has 64 GB RAM, RTX A4000 GPU, and a 16 core processor. I did `sudo update, upgrade, autoremove, clean`.